# Firefox Extension location.href not redirecting

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using something rather generic here, but essentially I want to be able to load a new tab at my desired URL when selecting my extension, then when at that tab, redirect to a new URL. (The add on should run some code at the first page before redirecting, but that's for another day).

The code I have at the moment is

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "redirect",
  label: "redirect",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
    tabs.open({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    onReady: loadRedirect
    });

  function loadRedirect(tab) {
    tab.attach({
      contentScript: "location.href = 'www.youtube.com;'"
    });
  }
}
```

When running this however, the 2nd URL appends to the first, rather than replaces, and then gets stuck in an infinite load/refresh loop until I close the browser.

I assume I'm missing something absolutely obvious, but I wasn't able to find anything while searching around.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the `location.href` to a string that has no scheme. It is assumed that it is a URL within the current domain.  Because it also does not start with a `/` it is assumed to be relative to the current page. Thus, it is appended to the current `google.com` URL. The page becomes ready; fires the `ready` event; and your `onReady` handler is called. Your handler then changes the URL, causing the page to be reloaded, and, again, fire the `ready` event, which starts the process over again. This is your infinite loop.

To actually get to `www.youtube.com`, you could change your code to:

```
function loadRedirect(tab) {
  tab.attach({
    contentScript: "location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com';"
  });
}
```

Which could have been done without the need to inject a content script by assigning to [`tab.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#url):

```
function loadRedirect(tab) {
  tab.url = 'https://www.youtube.com';
}
```

However, that will not prevent the infinite loop.  There are many ways to do so.  The easiest is to just remove the `ready` listener:

```
function loadRedirect(tab) {
  tab.off('ready',loadRedirect);
  tab.url = 'https://www.youtube.com';
}
```